# API PHP e JSON puxando banco e pasta

Tags: php, javascript

Olá! Estou trabalhando com um app com Cordova. Criei um uma API com PHP puxando de uma tabela do meu banco, porém nessa tabela existe uma coluna onde ela puxa várias imagens que estão em uma pasta.

O quero fazer é puxar as imagens especificas dessa pasta referente a id e chamar ela com json. Eu sei fazer isso normalmente com select mas uma pasta não sei como fazer.

Index

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/css/swiper.min.css">

  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #000;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/sports/1/">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400/sports/2/">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/800/sports/3/">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-white"></div>
    
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  </div>

  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.0.7/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
  </script>
```

Chamada PHP

```html
<?php
require_once 'bd.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
$pdo = conectar();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$listar = $pdo->query("select * from teste where id='$id'");
echo json_encode($listar->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

 ?>
```

Script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var html = '';

  var query = location.search.slice(1);
  var partesDaQuery = query.split("&");
  var json = {};

    partesDaQuery.forEach(function(partes){
      var chaveValor = partes.split('=');
      var paramsKey = chaveValor[0];
      var paramsValue = chaveValor[1];
      json[paramsKey] = paramsValue;


  $.getJSON('http://teste.com/api.php?id='+json[paramsKey], function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){

html += '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    html += '<div class="swiper-zoom-container">';
     html += '<img src="http://teste.com/volumes/01/">';
    html += '</div>';
        });
    $("#volumes").html(html);
  });

  });
});
```

Comment: tem código implementado ?

Comment: Tenho sim. Vou editar o post.

Comment: Adicionei, dá uma olhada. Repara que só está puxando o banco e não pasta.

Comment: já tentou inserir imagens no banco de dados em um campo novo ? pode facilitar sua vida, não ?

Comment: Mas no caso agr n vai adiantar. Cada item puxa várias imagens. Exemplo:
Volume 01 puxa umas 5 imagens.
Volume 02 puxa umas 2 imagens.
Quero identificar elas refente a ID e jogar pro slide.

Comment: então vamos lá, verifique que sua pasta imagens contém todas as imagens que necessita puxar, verifique que o nome da pasta no projeto está correto com o que está chamando no código, e ai vamos matando aos poucos os possíveis erros